# How to stream and play video using ffplay without buffering

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I want to stream a live webcam video and display it on android device with the lowest latency possible. I am streaming video from a computer over rtsp protocol and I am able to watch the stream with ~150ms latency on the second computer using `ffplay -fflags nobuffer rtsp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port/test.sdp` command.

So far I have successfully compiled [ffmpeg4android](https://github.com/chloette/ffmpeg4android) library. Unfortunately this library uses NDK which I am not familiar with. All I want to do is to be able to invoke the same command and display the video on the android SurfaceView.

How can I call for such command?

Comment: Streaming with 50ms latency?  That's basically impossible with today's technology, and especially on Android.  WebRTC is optimized on all devices, and is still a few hundred milliseconds typically.  That's about as best as it can get.

Comment: Well... It should be 150ms. I didn't notice missing '1'.

Comment: Try this: `ffplay -fflags nobuffer -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://<host>:<port>`